# iPhone 5 only uses 3.5 inches of screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, retina-display, ios-simulator

I'm developing an iPhone app (xcode 5). When I run my app on the 4inch simulator there is a black bar at the top and bottom of the app. The used screen space is only 3.5 inches. How do I have it use the entire screen?

I'm using a basic TableView in this app

Comment: Is your tableView's bound's hardcoded to be 480px high?  How do you set your frames?

Comment: You need a launch image of size 640 × 1136.  Call it Default-568h@2x.png or set the asset catalog for R4.